# Defining a list without knowing the number of elements

Tags: symbolic, variable-definitions

Let $N$ be a natural number $\ge 1$. I have two questions:

1. How can I define a list with variables $p_1,...,p_n$?
2. How can I define an element $a\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $a⁶=(-1)^n?$

Comment: By $n$ you mean $N$? (I am aware the post is 3yo)

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, you can use `Table`, as Anxon Pués wrote:

```
Table[Subscript[p, i], {i, n}]
```

However, this might be a bad choice, as discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/367). A better way is to define them as `p[1]`, `p[2]`,... etc, which can be done either with `Table` like this

```
Table[p[i],{i,n}]
```

or more conveniently with `Array` like this

```
Array[p,n]
```

As for your second question - it's not clear what you mean. There are 6 solutions to the equation you wrote. You can either do `Solve[x^6==(-1)^n,x]` to get all of them, or if you're using this inside other expressions you might want to use `Assumptions->x^6==(-1)^n`.

Comment: Thanks! For my second question: Later there will be sum of the generators containig an element $a$ with the assumption (depending on $n$) like in my second question. That's the reason.

Comment: If I type `Array[p,n]` is doesn't work. Maybe because $n$ is not fixed?

Comment: Indeed.  `n` has to be defined.

Answer (score -1):

1.

```
aaa[n_] := Table[Subscript[p, i], {i, n}]
```

2.

```
a \[Element] \[DoubleStruckCapitalC]
a^6 = (-1)^N

a[n_] := (-1)^(n/6)
```

Comment: My mistake, the $N$ from $2.$ should be the same as the $n$ from $1.$. I don't have to tell Mathematica, what $N$ is, i.e. natural and $\ge 1$?